# How to set diffrent image in TouchImageView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, zooming, touchimageview

I am using mike/ortiz [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView) class for zooming the image.In the xml i have used the image like this

```
 <com.example.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/iivAvailable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="00.0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/toxiraepro_ui_trans_new" 
        android:visibility="visible"/>
```

now i want zoom this image on click of the image button i have some image buttons which will show some points on image to touch. so is there any way to pass id or refrence of any other image in TouchImageView class

`

Comment: Take a look to this library https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: isn't any way i can make changes in existing code.

Comment: You can fork the repo

Comment: what does that mean ??

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo

Comment: that doesn't answer my question